# How does adaptative Huffman coding (Vitter algorithm) work?

Tags: huffman-coding

I have implemented Vitter algorithm thanks to the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adaptive_Huffman_coding). However I don't really understand how some parts of the algorithm make the algorithm more efficient:

```
 IF (new p is sibling to NYT) THEN
             leaf_to_increment = p
             p = parent of p
```

Here I don't understand why is the condition necessary. What would it change if we just removed this portion of the algorithm?

Also, in the slide and increment procedure, I don't understand why if the node is an internal node then p becomes the former parent of p while if it is a leaf node then p becomes the new parent of p.

```
 previous_p = parent of p
 IF (p is an internal node) THEN
         Slide p in the tree higher than the leaf nodes of weight wt + 1
         increase weight of p by 1
         p = previous_p
 ELSE
         Slide p in the tree higher than the internal nodes of weight wt
         increase weight of p by 1
         p = new parent of p.
```

Are these things here to preserve the Vitter invariant (block of leaves then block of internal nodes in ascending order of weight, from bottom to top, left to right..) or to improve the efficiency of the algorithm?

Also, how is it more efficient to "slide" the nodes instead of just swapping two nodes as in FGK algorithm? I can't find any interesting article about Vitter algorithm.